# Creating objects at runtime Nameing

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Say i have a class called TMachine
I currently create 1 class like so

```
 Machine := MachineShape.TMachine.create(self);
```

but I need more then 1, never really sure how many i need as it depends on # of machines in the database at the time, Should never be over 20. So I know i need an array of some type in the var section. Currently i have

```
procedure TFLayout1.GetClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  machine : TMachine;
begin
 .....

  //gets number of machines in total
  while not fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Eof do
    begin
      fdb.count := fdb.count+1;
      fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Next;
    end;

  //restarts back at first query
  fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.First;


  //creates the shape
  while not fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Eof do
    begin
        machine := MachineShape.TMachine.Create(self);
        machine.PlaceShape(44,44,'CM402','first','123/33/123');
        fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Next;
    end;
end;
```

currently that will place 1 machine on the form `"Machine"` . I Need it to place "Machine1"  "Machine2" ... for how ever many are in the query.  Thus `"machine"` needs replaced by an array some how?  everything is created at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest is to use a list. Use a generic list from `Generics.Collections`.

```
FList: TList<TMachine>;
```

For you needs, you would declare the list to be a field in one of your classes. The class that you want to control and manage all the machines.

Create it like this:

```
FList := TList<TMachine>.Create;
```

Add new members to the list like this:

```
FList.Add(Machine);
```

Iterate over the list like this:

```
for Machine in FList do
  Machine.DoSomething;
```

---

If you would like the list to control the lifetime of the machines, then use `TObjectList<T>` instead.

```
FList: TList<TMachine>;
....
FList := TObjectList<TMachine>.Create;
```

Then when you remove items from the list, clear the list, destroy the list etc., the machines will also be destroyed.

The Delphi documentation contains an [example illustrating the use of `TObjectList<T>`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/XE2/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectList_%28Delphi%29).

---

So, to make it clear, your `while` loop would look like this:

```
while not fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Eof do
begin
  machine := MachineShape.TMachine.Create(self);
  FList.Add(machine);
  machine.PlaceShape(44,44,'CM402','first','123/33/123');
  fdeptlayout.ADOQuery1.Next;
end;
```

Then at some other point in your code when you need to iterate over all machines, use the code in the `for` loop above.

---

Of course, this may all be a complete red herring. Perhaps you don't ever need to refer to your machine objects outside the routine in the question. In which case you don't need a list at all, and the code in the question is already perfectly adequate.

I note that you state:

> Currently that will place one machine on the form.

That is not so. The while loop will create one machine object for each iteration of your `while` loop. The fact that you re-use the local variable `machine` doesn't change that. Each time round the loop you call `TMachine.Create` and so create a new instance each iteration.

Comment: When i do `list.Add(Machine)` I dont have to change the name Machine, thus everytime i run list.add(machine)  i keep the text "machine" in there?

Comment: @GlenMorse `Machine` is just a local variable. It's not the name of the component. It's the name of your variable. Like any variable, it can hold different things at different times.

Comment: Thats, what i am having issues with.  I dont have a "set" name of machines, Cause i dont know the # of machines till after the query is ran from DB.  Thus i need a way to make "Machine" change. I do like the TObjectList, as i was wondering how i was going to kill them all. but still need the var part

Comment: You can use that same local variable named `Machine` for each and every new machine that you create.

Comment: The procedure PlaceShape Does all i need to the shapes, I never knew i could call them all one var though?

Comment: @Glen Yes, see my latest update. Perhaps you don't need a list at all. It's still useful knowledge in case you ever have to remember the objects for future use. But your current code already creates multiples objects.

Comment: um, Thats great. But I figured that was the reason it was not working right... guess ill have to post another question on why its not placeing them correctly.

Comment: @GlenMorse, you should learn a little bit about Pointers and Refernece Types, even if you never intend to use Pointers. I personally couldn't possibly explain to you why using a single variable works in this case, it's such basic information. And you will not get far without this: if you don't understand this concepts you can't safely work with lists and runtime created objects, you'll leak memory and that will eventually crash your application.

Comment: @Cosmin is right. You are missing some basic programming knowledge. Your best course of action right now is to go back to basics and fill in the missing gaps.

Comment: I can see how it works, but i just dont understand why it would not overwrite the previous values for "machine"  As i cant place a Tshape on the forum and call it shape1 then put another shape on the form and call it shape1... just figured it was the same thing using a var

Comment: The reason is that `machine` is not the object. The variable `machine` is just a reference to the object. When you assign to `machine` for the second time you are simply pointing that reference at a different object. The first object remains. But you no longer have a ready reference to it.

Comment: Lol this could get long,  but in short, the var machine is not the name. The name is actually what ever delphi decides to assign it.  No need to go back to the beginning for that :P

Comment: That's exactly right. Now, for a published field in a Delphi form, for example `Button1: TButton`, that is managed by the form designer, it so happens that the variable name and the component name are the same. But when you are managing the component construction, there's no reason nor need to make the variable name and component name match.

Answer (score 2):

You can place the machines in a TObjectList

In your class definition add

```
FMachines: TObjectList<TMachine>;
```

Then in your FormCreate:

```
FMachines:= TObjectList<TMachine>.Create;
```

and in FormDestroy:

```
FMachines.Free;
```

In your GetClick method dd the created machine to the list like so:

```
machine := MachineShape.TMachine.Create(self);
FMachines.Add(machine);
```

You can then refer to the created machines by accessing the FMachines list.

Comment: So in my //creates the shape  While not loop, i would add the fMachines.Add(machine);  there, correct

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what you would do. Have you ever used `TList`? Or even a Delphi string list? The concept is just the same.